# Display [x, x] grid with [y, y] size in Processing

Tags: graphics, processing, rendering

I have a 2d array, let's say [500][500]. I want to render that array onto a [200][200] grid, where I will render each pixel from the second array onto my computer.

How do I render my [500][500] grid to a [200][200] space? Thanks!

This is how I'm rendering a [200, 200] grid (processing code):

```
void render() {
  loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      int i = y * width + x;
      pixels[i] = color(grid[x][y]*RMULT, grid[x][y]*GMULT, grid[x][y]*BMULT);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using scale() to draw it?

Comment: scale() doesn't seem to work when you're drawing with the pixel array.

Comment: I was drawing the grid without using a pixel array, but merely decreasing the size of each rectangle.

Comment: This would not work since drawing rectangles takes too long. I use the pixel array in order to make sure I can render it quickly.

Comment: Look, it will be better if You will provide full working code.

Comment: You have to make your i-loop based on the number of pixel to render, not the size of the array